# react-native run-android adb failed to stat app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run my react native app v0.53 after create new app and I get the error

```
Total time: 21.148 secs
Could not build the app, read the error above for details.

Running C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 29d84044 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Installing the app on the device (cd android && adb -s 29d84044 install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
adb: failed to stat app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk: No such file or directory
Command failed: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 29d84044 install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

Starting the app on 29d84044 (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 29d84044 shell am start -n com.sleepcalculator/com.sleepcalculator.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.sleepcalculator/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.sleepcalculator/com.sleepcalculator.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

error

```
     What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

what I already tried to do:
remove npm cache, npm install, remove android cache

Comment: Can you add the "error above" that is being referenced?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post

Comment: Can you post the full log? You're missing the errors from AAPT.

Comment: Your application is not getting compiled. That is the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have already installed app with the same package name, so make sure you delete it first from your phone/emulator. Once you do that, try to run the app again.

If that didn't help check this thread:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14952

Comment: it was the solution for me issue, in addition I run "react-native upgrade" in the project